# Custom TSLint rule to check function parameter assignability (no bivariance)

Tags: typescript, tslint

I just stumbled upon the fact that TypeScript isn't quite strict checking the assignability of functions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance

Unfortunately, for some patterns parameter bivariance misses important type checking. So I'm wondering whether it would be possible to build a custom TSLint rule telling me when I'm doing something like this:

```
interface Base {}
interface BaseEx extends Base { x; }

let fn1: (a: Base) => void;
let fn2: (b: BaseEx) => void;

fn1 = fn2; // TSLint: parameter (a: BaseEx) is not assignable to (b: Base)
```

However, documentation on creating custom TSLint rules seems rather incomplete, I only found a single example of a purely syntactical check. I would be really happy if you could advise me a resource to learn how to extend TSLint with semantic rules like this one.

Comment: Have you looked at the GitHub repo? It has the source for [all of the built-in rules](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/tree/master/src/rules)? I think the best resource will be the TSLint source itself.

Comment: Yes, but these rules are all quite simple - they all seem to do tree walking, not semantics. Could it be that one has to use the typescript NPM module to access semantic functionality? In this case I will update my question. What do you think?

Comment: @bloxx did you end up making any progress on this endeavour? I also feel let down by TypeScript for the same reasons, but I understand that trade-offs were made (as you can read here, if you haven't already: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825).

Comment: No, I did not, it felt like I was still missing some knowledge about how TypeScript works. As you said - I'd really enjoy stricter type checking rules but I also understand that that's a complicated topic and the TypeScript team has to look in all directions for inconsistencies (apart for bivariance, I think TypeScript's type system is more powerful than most other ones, I really like it...). Hmmm... Maybe I'll look at it again later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking to implement a custom rule, the TSLint source code is a useful resource for guidance. The source for all of the built-in rules is available in the [TSLint repo](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/tree/9248e056c1a652ee13597e68da26cacf0b87e134/src/rules). Most of the rules to not require access to type information. However, there are two that do:

- the [`no-for-in-array`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/a00915d116601619481c1d562bd16e9ad36b884f/src/rules/noForInArrayRule.ts) rule; and
- the [`restrict-plus-operands`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/9248e056c1a652ee13597e68da26cacf0b87e134/src/rules/restrictPlusOperandsRule.ts) rule.

Those rules use the [`ProgramAwareRuleWalker`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/9248e056c1a652ee13597e68da26cacf0b87e134/src/language/walker/programAwareRuleWalker.ts), which makes type information available to the rule via the [`TypeChecker`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/9248e056c1a652ee13597e68da26cacf0b87e134/src/language/walker/programAwareRuleWalker.ts#L36-L38).

There is some information on how the `TypeChecker` can be used in the [TypeScript Compiler API documenation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker).

If rules that use the `ProgramAwareRuleWalker` are enabled, TSLint must be run with the `--type-check` option and a `--project` must be specified, too.

Comment: Great, I didn't notice that! I think this will help.